# Deck de cartas aleatorio

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

estou criando um site para pessoas jogarem cartas com php. Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um deck de 50 cartas para cada pessoa. No banco de dados tenho uma tabela com 300 cartas diferentes e dessas 300 cartas quero que ao usuário se cadastrar gere 50 cartas aleatórias das 300 que eu tenho na tabela para o deck dele. Imagino que tenha haver com array e random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o RAND() do MySQL (estou usando a classe PDO do PHP pra acessar o bd):

```
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sua_tabela ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50";
    $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
```

A variável $sql é um array com 50 valores do banco de dados.

Comment: Lembrando que o `RAND()` não é CSPRNG, criptograficamente-seguro, segundo a própria documentação "RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator". Acho que para proposito de cartas ele não deve ser utilizado em nenhuma hipótese.  Já há vários casos sobre isso, no mesmo contexto de cartas, [esse foi que achei agora](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/10923_616221_3/How-We-Learned-to-Cheat-at-Online-Poker-A-Study-in-Software-Security.htm).

Comment: Você tem alguma sugestão segura, inkeliz?

Comment: Para a aplicação em questão o rand() se aplica.

Comment: Beleza pessoal, vlw pelas dicas!

Answer (score 1):

Para uso geral a resposta do @Leandro pode ser utilizada. Entretanto por ser um jogo de carta, embora previsibilidade não seja algo tão fácil... ainda é possível, por isso o meu comentário.

Inclusive por lei em alguns casos, é preciso que utiliza um gerador verdadeiramente aleatório, um hardware dedicado para isso, ou ao menos um CSPRNG. Em websites de poker que são regulamentados passam por testes, por exemplo o Gaming Labs, [eles tem testes próprios](http://www.gaminglabs.com/technical-specifications-for-rng-testing) e específicos para testar o gerador. Mas, essas questões são mais burocráticas, fora do assunto do StackOverflow, apenas menciono aqui porque não acredito que seja algo "irrelevante".

---

> Requer PHP 7+

O `RAND()` do MySQL não é um CSPRNG, eles mesmo não garantem isso. O PHP possui uma função própria que é a `random_int` e o `random_bytes` que alega ser um CSPRNG, ele usa o `/dev/urandom`.

Ele deve ser mais confiável do que o `RAND()` do MySQL, para isso você pode utilizar:

```
function gerar(int $quantidade, int $minimo, int $maximo) : array
{
    $arr = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $quantidade; $i++) {
        $arr[] = random_int($minimo, $maximo);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Isso irá gerar X números usando o `random_int`, portanto poderá pegar os dados da seguinte maneira:

```
$numerosGerados = gerar(50, 0, 299);

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 'SELECT coluna FROM tabela WHERE id IN ('.substr(str_repeat('?,', count($numerosGerados)),0,-1).')');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, str_repeat('i', count($numerosGerados)), ...$numerosGerados);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$resultado = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    echo $linha['coluna'];
}
```

---

Isso parte de algumas premissas:

1. A tabela está em ordem e possui um campo de `0` até `299`.
2. Pode haver cartas repetidas.

O ideal na verdade é que você armazena as cartas geradas numa nova tabela associada ao jogador, assim poderá verificar se realmente o jogador possui a carta que ele diz ter jogado, por exemplo.